# How do I add array and integer data in c# just like c++/c

Tags: c#, label

Okay what I want to do is add data of array and an integer to a text statement/label. For eg in C or c++ what we do is :
`printf("Total sales of %d agents is : %d" , x , totalSales[i]);`

Now I want to do the same in C# , The data I have is an integer **int x** which is user inputted and is the total number of agents. And I have an array of total sales **totalSales[x]** which contains total sales for all individual agents. Now I want to show it on screen as a label. How do I do it like the above c/c++ method? What is the substitute of %d in c#.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine($"Total sales of {x} agents is : {totalSales[i]}");`

Comment: or `Console.WriteLine("Total sales of {0} agents is : {1}",x ,totalSales[i]);`

Comment: Okay can I resize and position where this output will be or is there a way to do this using the label tool , **label.text**

Comment: You can set the value of the `Text` property to `$"Total sales of {x} agents is : {totalSales[i]}"`. Size and positioning of the label is dependent on the UI framework in question.

Comment: Got it , thanks everyone

Comment: FYI, C++ has `std::ostringstream` for formatting text to a `std::string`.  The C language doesn't have this (another example of how C and C++ are different languages).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is string interpolation:

```
Console.WriteLine($"Total sales of {x} agents is : {totalSales[i]}");
```